# Load more recycler view with SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

There is one activity in which there are multiple fragments.

First fragment is WriteFragment in which there are two edit text fields, one insert button and one read button.

Clicking on insert button inserts entries presented in edit text field to SQLite database.

Clicking on read button reads data from SQLite database and show it on recycler view.

However, data should be shown in bunch of maximum 4.

When user reaches at the bottom, it should show cyclic progress bar for 2 seconds after which it should show another set having maximum of 4 data.

If remaining data is less than 4, it should be shown at once.

Now, the problem is: -

read call reads data from the beginning every time even though I am changing start, end and slot (bunch, set) values every time.

Suppose there are 4 data and I am calling read_fragment. it will show first 4 data properly. Now I am going back to write_fragment and do some insert operation. Now, this time when I am calling read_fragment, it shows first 4 data initially and then after cyclic progress bar loading for 2 seconds, it is showing once again those 4 data and then it will show rest of the data. The process repeats!

I can not understand why it loads same data?! Why loadMoreData() method is not working as expected?!

Below is my DBHelper class:_

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String MyDb = "MyDb.db";
private static String MyTable = "MyTable";
private static String id = "id";
private static String fname = "fname";
private static String lname = "lname";
private static int version = 1;
private static final ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<>();

private static final String sql =  "create table " + MyTable + " ( " + id + " integer primary key autoincrement, "

                                                   + fname + " text, "

                                                   + lname + " text )";

DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, MyDb, null, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

void insert (User user) {

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(fname, user.getFname());
    contentValues.put(lname, user.getLname());
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(MyTable, id, contentValues);
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
}

ArrayList<User> read () {

    /*We are required to have readable database to read data*/

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();

    /*Columns that we want to read*/

    String [] columns = {id, fname, lname};

    /*Query to read database*/

    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MyTable, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    /*cursor.move(cursorPosition);*/ // Move the cursor by a relative amount, forward or backward, from the current position.

    /*cursor.moveToPosition(cursorPosition);*/ // Move the cursor to an absolute position.

    while (cursor.moveToNext()){

        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        String fname = cursor.getString(1);
        String lname = cursor.getString(2);

        User user = new User();
        user.setId(id);
        user.setFname(fname);
        user.setLname(lname);
        list.add(user);
    }

    return list;
}

public void deleteItem(int position) {

    //Open the database

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    //Execute sql query to remove from database

    //NOTE: When removing by String in SQL, value must be enclosed with ''

    /*Following is the query way to delete an item. We can also perform, call delete function on our database as well*/

    database.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + MyTable + " WHERE " + id + "= '" + position + "'");

    //Close the database

    database.close();
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

Below is my read_fragment class:_

```
public class ReadFragment extends android.app.Fragment {

RecyclerView recyclerView;

RvAdapter rvAdapter;

ArrayList<User> ulist = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<User> partialList = new ArrayList<>();

User udata = new User();

public ReadFragment() {

    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,

                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_read, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity());

    ulist = dbHelper.read();

    loadMoreData();

    rvAdapter = new RvAdapter(partialList, recyclerView, getActivity());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapter);

    rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    rvAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {

        @Override

        public void onLoadMore() {

            Log.e("onLoadMore", "Load More");

            partialList.add(null); // Adding null will give ItemViewType as cyclic progressBar to viewHolder

            rvAdapter.notifyItemInserted(partialList.size() - 1);

            //Load more data for reyclerview

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Log.e("run", "Load More 2");

                    //Remove loading item

                    partialList.remove(partialList.size() - 1); // This will remove cyclic progressBar

                    rvAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(partialList.size());

                    //Load data

                    loadMoreData();

                    rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    rvAdapter.setLoaded();

                }

            }, 2000);
        }
    });

    return v;
}

public void loadMoreData() {

    int end = ulist.size() - 1;

    int start = partialList.size();

    int bunch = start + 3;

    if (bunch <= end) {

        for (int i = start; i <= bunch; i++) {

            udata = ulist.get(i);

            partialList.add(udata);
        }

    } else {

        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {

            udata = ulist.get(i);

            partialList.add(udata);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Below is my RecyclerView adapter class:_

```
class RvAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 0;

private final int VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 1;

private boolean isLoading;

private int visibleThreshold = 5;

private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;

private ArrayList<User> ulist;

private OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener;

RvAdapter(ArrayList<User> ulist, RecyclerView recyclerView, Activity activity) {

    this.ulist = ulist;

    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(activity);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();

            lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

            if (!isLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {

                if (mOnLoadMoreListener != null) {

                    mOnLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                }

                isLoading = true;
            }
        }
    });
}

void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener) {

    this.mOnLoadMoreListener = mOnLoadMoreListener;
}

private static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView tv_id, tv_fname, tv_lname;

    private ImageButton deleteButton;

    private ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        tv_id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_id);

        tv_fname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_fname);

        tv_lname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_lname);

        deleteButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
    }
}

private static class LoadingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    private LoadingViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }
}

@Override public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model, parent, false);

        return new ItemViewHolder(view);

    } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_LOADING) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.loading_layout, parent, false);

        return new LoadingViewHolder(view);
    }

    return null;
}

@Override public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (holder instanceof ItemViewHolder) {

        User user = ulist.get(position);

        ItemViewHolder userViewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;

        userViewHolder.tv_id.setText(String.valueOf(user.getId()));

        userViewHolder.tv_fname.setText(user.getFname());

        userViewHolder.tv_lname.setText(user.getLname());

    } else if (holder instanceof LoadingViewHolder) {

        LoadingViewHolder loadingViewHolder = (LoadingViewHolder) holder;

        loadingViewHolder.progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
}

@Override public int getItemCount() {

    return ulist == null ? 0 : ulist.size();
}

@Override public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return ulist.get(position) == null ? VIEW_TYPE_LOADING : VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
}

void setLoaded() {

    isLoading = false;
}
```

}

I have also tried following logic for loadMoreData():_

```
start = partialList.size();

    for (int i = start; i <= start + 3; i++) {

        if (ulist.size() > slot) {

            slot = i + 1;

            udata = ulist.get(i);

            partialList.add(udata);
        }
    }

    start = partialList.size();
```

However, with no luck, still I am getting list from the very beginning after each and every scroll event!!!

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance for giving your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link for Load More RecyclerView and Bottom ProgressBar 
[Load More RecyclerView and Bottom ProgressBar](https://androidreality.blogspot.in/2017/02/load-more-recyclerview-and-bottom.html)

Comment: can you tell me why the variable int I inside for loop of loadMoreData() method always starts with 0 for each and every scroll event? Which is the reason I think because of which after each scroll event, I am getting data from the very beginning!!! You can point me out if the reason is something else!!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was getting same data multiple times was because of final ArrayList. So, it is something like, final keyword sets the variable with fixed value but as i was modifying that variable somehow, it was giving me new list everytime which obviously would have all values including the new one. So, it is something like it was creating new object of ArrayList every time. However, If someone can confirm what i have concluded and explain the process behind the scene in clear and better way, it will be appreciated.